# How to call Controller in Module?

Tags: form, controller, elementaction, classes, modules

I'm very new to craft and I'm having trouble finding an answer to my question (I've scoured the questions on here - but the only answers appear to be for plugins).

Basically, I want to submit a form to an action in a controller - which will be inside a Module.

I have this form in a template:

`<form method="post" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="site/say">
    <input class="btn submit" type="submit" value="submit me">
</form>`

I'm trying to get it to go to this controller (which is in modules/controllers/SiteController):

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use yii\web\Controller;

class SiteController extends Controller
{
    // ...existing code...

    public function actionSay($message = 'Hello')
    {
        die('in say action');
    }
}
```

I'm constantly getting a 404 - I've tried different variations for the value of action, e.g. actions/site/say.
Do I need to add a route somewhere like in Laravel? 
Really, really stuck on this, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You need to include your module handle to the route

```
module-handle/site/say
```

You also should use the correct namespace instead of `app/controllers` I suggest you to read the documentation

You can as well define a [route](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/updating-plugins.html#routing-hooks) if you like